# Justify: since $\nabla f(\cdot)$ is continuous, therefore $\int\limits_0^1 (\nabla^2 f(x+ tp) - \nabla^2 f(x))pdt = o(\|p\|)$

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, proof-explanation, convex-optimization

This is a claim from Nocedal and Wright's text on optimization 2nd ed p.23.

Suppose $f$ is $C^2$, then $\exists t \in (0,1)$, such that

$\nabla f(x+p) = \nabla f(x) + \int\limits_0^1 \nabla^2 f(x+ p)pdt$

Equivalently,

$\nabla f(x+p) = \nabla f(x) + \nabla^2f(x)p + \int\limits_0^1 (\nabla^2 f(x+ p) -
 \nabla^2 f(x))pdt$

However, next comes the confounding claim:

> Claim: Since $\nabla f(\cdot)$ is continuous, therefore
>   $$\int\limits_0^1 (\nabla^2 f(x+ tp) -  \nabla^2 f(x))pdt = o(\|p\|)$$

Note: in the text, it was defined: if $\eta(\cdot):\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, \eta(\nu) = o(\nu)$ if $\eta(\nu)/\nu \to 0$ as $\nu \to 0$ or $\nu \to \infty$

**Questions**:

- How was continuity used? For me, a vector valued function is
  continuous if all its components are continuity. I can't see how to go
  from $\dfrac{\partial f(\cdot)}{\partial x_i}, \forall i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$ is continuous to that
  integral with the Hessian being continuous.
- How do we justify the $o(\|p\|)$ bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$| \int\limits_0^1 (\nabla^2 f(x+ tp) - \nabla^2 f(x))~p ~dt | \leq \int\limits_0^1 |(\nabla^2 f(x+ tp) - \nabla^2 f(x))p |~dt$$

By Cauchy Swartz inequality we get;

$$| \int\limits_0^1 (\nabla^2 f(x+ tp) - \nabla^2 f(x))~p ~dt | \leq \int\limits_0^1 \| \nabla^2 f(x+ tp) - \nabla^2 f(x) \|~\|p \|  ~ dt  $$

By mean value theorem for integrals;  for all $p$ there is a scalar $s_p \in  [0,1]$ such that 
$$\int\limits_0^1 \| \nabla^2 f(x+ tp) - \nabla^2 f(x) \|~\|p \|  ~ dt =  \| \nabla^2 f(x+ s_pp) - \nabla^2 f(x) \|~\|p \|   $$ Therefore we finally arrive

$$  \frac{| \int\limits_0^1 (\nabla^2 f(x+ tp) - \nabla^2 f(x))~p ~dt |}{\|p\|}  \leq \| \nabla^2 f(x+ s_pp) - \nabla^2 f(x) \| $$

Now by letting $p \to 0$ we get the desired result.